# How does ActiveRecord search for connection adapters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement a connection adapter but for some reason ActiveRecord doesn't see it. Any ideas on how does it translate the name in `config/database.yml` to class name to load?

```
# ~/my_gems/synapse_db_adapter/lib/synapse_db_adapter.rb

require 'active_record/connection_adapters/synapse_db_adapter'

# ~/my_gems/synapse_db_adapter/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/synapse_db_adapter.rb

require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter'

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SynapseDbAdapter < AbstractAdapter
    end
  end
end

# ~/test_app/config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: synapse_db
```

When running test Rails application I'm getting `database configuration specifies nonexistent synapse_db adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound)`

Comment: there is no such adapter name like synapse_db

Answer (score 2):

It turns out `ActiveRecord::Base` should contain a method `adapter_name_connection`, in my case `synapse_db_connection`.